# Who is Ashirah in Hebrew mythology?

Tags: folklore

When I heard about the myth regarding Asherah as God’s “wife”, it started to appear some questions which I’d like to ask because I could not find the answers I’m looking for. Here is a list questions:

1. Is Asherah a created goddess?
2. Was Asherah always existed alongside with God?
3. How she became God’s “wife”?

Just in curiosity.

**Note:** Sorry if I have selected this tag in case you think it is wrong. I have selected this one because I could not find appropriate tags for it, and I did not know what to do and so, I have chosen this one. If you know what tags to select for this one, can you please tell me in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

Judaism wasn't always monotheistic. In fact, the "many names of God" listed in the [Tetragrammaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton) and other sources are clearly derived from deities worshipped in cities in and around Hebrew lands before the [diaspora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora). For example, the name Baal is clearly derived from the Canaanite deity [Ba'al Haddu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadad). The "many names of God" in Genesis is very likely an attempt to establish a national,  central authority of these deities under one and the same, Yahweh.

Asharah is a female deity from this pre-monotheistic period, known from Akkadian and Hittite texts. During the transition period from poly- to monotheism, some biblical scholars believe that Asherah was worshipped as the consort of Yahweh.

Scholars have also found an early [link between Asherah and Eve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802828523), based upon the coincidence of their common title as "the mother of all living" in Genesis 3:20 through the identification with the Hurrian mother goddess [Hebat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B8%AAepat). Asherah was also given the title *Chawat* from which the name *Hawwah* in Aramaic and the biblical name *Eve* are derived.